# Transferring existing SCSS file to CSS

Tags: css, sass, shopify

The Shopify website I'm working with has its theme files in SCSS but I want to transfer them to CSS. I've tried with a few compilers but all of them show a bunch of errors. Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: I recommend [`webpack`](https://webpack.js.org/)

Answer (score 0):

This website was recommended to me by my web development program:

https://scout-app.io/

You could also use this parcel plugin.

https://v2.parceljs.org/languages/sass/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do a simple one-off conversion I suggest https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css. Click on *Load Data* and upload your *.scss* file. The conversion will happen automatically and you'll be able to download the resulting *.css* file.

For the future you might have better luck in your searches by using the terms *compile* or *convert* instead of *transfer*.